# How to write out this result? 10^116.75

Tags: exponential-sum

I entered the following into my calculator:

```
10^116.75
```

And from a Google Search, I landed on this:

```
5.623413e+116
```

Comment: What is your question precisely?  What don't you understand?

Comment: $a^{\frac b c} = \sqrt[c]{a^b}$

Comment: I have computed y for y = a + bx, but want to convert the y to x. So x = value^y.

Comment: @user12986714, can you explain? Show me an example?

Comment: @JohnSmith $y=a+bx\iff x=\frac{y-a}b$ this is what you should do if you want to convert y to x (for $y=a+bx$)

Comment: What does the second equation mean?

Comment: Example: $8^{\frac 4 3} = \sqrt[3]{8^4} = 16$

Comment: That's just a way of writing $5.623413\cdot10^{116}$

Comment: x=y−ab = gives me a 10, not sure of how to interpret this?

Comment: I think it would help if you showed us more of the problem you are actually working on, because it makes no sense that after solving $y=a+bx$ you would need $x=10^y.$ Either you are using the same symbol $x$ for two different things or there's some misconception in your method. Showing the actual problem would help people say how to interpret things; as it stands we really have no way to know what this is really about.

Comment: I think it would also help if you learned to do your own MathJax formattting: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$10^{116.75}=$

$=10^{0.75}\cdot10^{116}=$

$=10^{\frac{3}{4}}\cdot10^{116}=$

$=\sqrt[4]{1000}\cdot10^{116}\simeq$

$\simeq5.6234132519\cdot10^{116}$